# PHP SQLite Update Statement Not Working

Tags: php, sqlite

I've been looking at this for days now and can't seem to get it updating. Pretty simple - I'm tapping into the blockchain.info API, storing some information in an SQLite db and then running a Cron job to check whether transaction number has changed at all for a BTC address all in PHP.

My recent piece runs and when I echo all of my needed variables they all appear, but I just can't get it to update the db file?! I have also tried without single quotes in the update query. Feels like I've tried a lot of variations of this but to no avail yet. Any help would be appreciated!

Here it is:

```
    if ("$current_trans_number > $first_trans_number") {

        echo "Updates to transactions for address $btc<br/>";

        $stmt = $db->prepare("UPDATE logging SET balance_now = ':curr_bal', n_tx_now = ':curr_trans' WHERE logging_id = ':record_id'");

        $stmt->bindParam(':record_id', $logging_id); 
        $stmt->bindParam(':curr_bal', $current_balance);  
        $stmt->bindParam(':current_trans', $current_trans_number);  
        $stmt->execute();

    } else {
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to get rid of the single quotes around the placeholders:

```
UPDATE logging SET balance_now = :curr_bal, n_tx_now = :curr_trans WHERE logging_id = :record_id
```

And you should setup PDO to throw an exception when something is wrong. And you should display errors and warnings during development so that you will see if there is for example a problem with undefined variables.

Also note that your statement will always evaluate to true:

```
if ("$current_trans_number > $first_trans_number") {
```

You are evaluating a string and that evaluates to `true`.

You need:

```
if ($current_trans_number > $first_trans_number) {
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply jeroen. I've removed the single quotes and altered the if statement (good spot) - although still no difference. 

My script does throw errors when something isn't right, but in this case it is still running but not updating...